# How to find minimum even number from a vector using comparator

Tags: c++, stl

Eg: 2,3,4,5,6.
The expected output should be 2.

How can I write comparator func for min_element func to get the smallest even number.

```
auto mini_even=*min_element(vec.begin(),vec.end(),cmp);
```

Comment: What happen if only vector has only odd numbers?

Comment: When the function compares two even numbers, the smaller is less than the larger; when it compares an even number with an odd number, the even number is smaller; when it compares to odd numbers, one is less than the other, and it doesn't matter which.

Comment: `const auto projection = [](int n) { return std::make_pair(is_odd(n), n); }; const auto comp = [=](int lhs, int rhs){ return projection (lhs) < projection (rhs); };`.

Comment: Which version of C++? In C++20 there are ranges which makes this quite nice.

Comment: @Jarod42 very elegant, i couldnt resist to steal it for my answer :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a comparator that puts all even numbers before odd ones, ie any even number compares less than any odd, while all other comparisons are as usual:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{   
    std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3};
    
    auto cmp = [](int a,int b){
        if (a%2 == b%2) return a < b;
        if (a%2) return false;    // a odd  b even
        return true;              // a even b odd
    };
    auto mini_even=*min_element(vec.begin(),vec.end(),cmp);
    std::cout << mini_even;

}
```

To handle the case of a vector that only contains odd numbers you should check if the result is even or not.

The same effect can be achieved with a more elegant way of defining the comparator, as suggested by Jarod42 in a comment:

> ```
> const auto projection = [](int n) { return std::make_pair(is_odd(n), n); }; 
> const auto comp = [=](int lhs, int rhs){ return projection (lhs) < projection (rhs); };
> ```

`std::pair`s have an `operator<` that will, same as the above, place all even numbers (the ones where `is_odd` is `false`) before the odd ones.

---

And if you want to follow common practice to return `vec.end()` when the desired element cannot be found, you can wrap it in a function:

```
template <typename IT>
IT min_even(IT first, IT last) {
    if (first == last) return last;
    auto cmp = .... see above ...
    auto it = min_element(first,last,cmp);
    if (*it % 2) return last;
    return it;
}
```

Which can be generalized to work for any predicate:

```
template <typename IT, typename Predicate> 
IT min_proj(IT first,IT last,Predicate pred){
    if (first == last) return last;
    const auto projection = [pred](int n) { return std::make_pair(!pred(n), n); }; 
    const auto cmp = [=](int lhs, int rhs){ return projection (lhs) < projection (rhs); };
    auto it = min_element(first,last,cmp);
    if (!pred(*it)) return last;
    return it;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Tx1bKczc8)

Comment: This has one problem. If there is no even numbers `vec.end()` should be returned: https://godbolt.org/z/avsqv35zs

Comment: @MarekR hm ok, I added that to the answer. Actually not sure if I would do it in my code, or if instead of checking for `== end` i would just check for `%2 == 0`. Well, perhaps yes wrap it ;)

Comment: @MarekR wrapping it generalizes more nicely. I mean `min_even` could be templated on the projection to be made easily